# logic expression in bison

Tags: expression, grammar, bison, flex-lexer

Hello am trying to make a parser for a language.

But the parser returns me an error when i put an logic expression like this: X > 5 into an if expression.

for example if i make this statement: `if (x>5) a=3;`
then parser returns me an error condition x>5.

I am trying fix the problem without result.
I am newbie in flex/bison.

Any help;

here is the flex file:

```
`.....

"!"             {return NOT;}

"+" | "-"       {return MONAD_OPERATOR;}

"*" | "/" | "%"     {return DIAD_OPERATOR;}

"==" | "!=" | ">" | "<" | ">=" | "<="   {return SXES_OPERATOR;}

...`
```

and here is the bison file:

```
...

    if_statement : IF '(' logic_expression ')' statement NEWLINE
                 | IF '(' logic_expression ')' statement ELSE statement NEWLINE
                 ;  ;
    logic_expression : 
        logic_expression sxes_operator logic_expression
        | ID
        | NUM
        | logic_expression diad_operator logic_expression
        | '(' logic_expression ')'
        | NOT logic_expression
        | logic_expression log_operator logic_expression
        ;

monad_operator : MONAD_OPERATOR ; 
diad_operator : DIAD_OPERATOR ;
sxes_operator : SXES_OPERATOR ;
```

Comment: Doesn't bison complain that the grammar has shift-reduce conflicts?

Comment: Yes. I must expunge them? Doesn't parser work with them?

Comment: Most of the time, the parser will do something reasonable with shift-reduce conflicts. But it might not be what you expect it to do, so yes, you should fix them. Sometimes you get unexpected syntax errors, especially if you have reduce-reduce conflicts.

Comment: So you tell me the logic expression rules creates conflicts and i must fix it?can you tell one line with this conflict so i can understand how to fix it?I know what this conflict is but theoretically and i cant find and fix it in real project.

Comment: The grammar is ambiguous, so there will be conflicts. I don't know how many, but I suspect a lot. Also, I'd avoid using unnecessary non-terminals (`diad_operator`) for what could be terminals (`DYAD_OPERATOR`). Here's an ambiguity:  `a < 3 + 4` You grammar allows both `[[[a] < [3]] + [4]]` and `[[a] < [[3] + [4]]]` as parses (using `[...]` to indicate a `logic_expression`)

Comment: defined the rules for `"!="`, `">="`, `"<="` before `"!"`, `"<"`, `">"`. additionally I prefers `[]` instead `""`.

Answer (score 0):

(This question was answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

@rici noted that the grammar had shift-reduce conflicts:

> Most of the time, the parser will do something reasonable with
>   shift-reduce conflicts. But it might not be what you expect it to do,
>   so yes, you should fix them. Sometimes you get unexpected syntax
>   errors, especially if you have reduce-reduce conflicts.
>
> The grammar is ambiguous, so there will be conflicts. I don't know how
>   many, but I suspect a lot. Also, I'd avoid using unnecessary
>   non-terminals (`diad_operator`) for what could be terminals
>   (`DYAD_OPERATOR`). Here's an ambiguity: `a < 3 + 4` You grammar allows
>   both `[[[a] < [3]] + [4]]` and `[[a] < [[3] + [4]]]` as parses (using
>   `[...]` to indicate a `logic_expression`)

@Grijesh Chauhan concluded with:

> defined the rules for `"!="`, `">="`, `"<="` before `"!"`, `"<"`, `">"`.
>   additionally I prefers `[]` instead `""`